# Открыть файл Html из приложения

Tags: java, android

Можно ли как-нибудь при нажатии на кнопку, чтобы открывался в браузере файл html.
Я закинул его в папку assets а что дальше делать не знаю.

Comment: погугли WebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Папка `assets` не находится в поле видимости других браузеров. У вас есть два варианта

1. Сохранить `.html` файл в папку, видимую другим приложениям. В этом случае Вам надо будет запрашивать у пользователя права на запись/чтение.
2. Воспользоваться WebView для загрузки html-файлов из папки ассетов:

   ```
   WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
   wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); //вместо index имя Вашего файла
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Вы можете исполнить файл в браузере, введя в адресную строку браузера

`имя_сайта/assets/имя_html_файла.html`

Comment: а мне надо чтобы ссылалось на браузер и тм открывалось сразу